# What do professional commercial pilots do to counteract boredom?

Tags: pilots, commercial-operations

With the eyes of a layman, it seems to be a wonderful thing to fly a big airplane between continents. From an initial perspective anyway.

During a transatlantic fight, pilots can see the water of the ocean, and the never changing readouts in the cockpit. Years long. Decades long. Only the water, the clouds, the sky, the sun and the sensor readings.

Until they retire!

Ok, maybe they could get a laptop with them and play on that, but I think it is probably against the rules.

Isn't it something like a prison for life? How pilots deal with the increasing boredom?